# How to deploy Flask Web in Python2.7 32bit on the 64bit Windows 10

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I wanna deploy my flask web project on my Windows 10 OS, I choose Apache2.4 and mod_wsgi to deploy it.
The environment is shown as below:

1. python 2.7 32bit
2. window10 64bit
3. mod_wsgi‑4.4.23+ap24vc9‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
4. apache2.4 V9 32bit

I follow the common steps(shows in [enter link description here](http://csparpa.github.io/blog/2013/03/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver.html))

step1. download apache2.4 32 bit complied by VC9

step2. download mod_wsgi 4.3 32 bit complied by VC9

step3. put the mod_wsgi.so in the directory mod_wsgi/data/ in the the directory Apache24/modules

step4. modify the config file(like port no and path) and add:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

step5. add the path of my web project in the http.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
<Directory D:/developer/workspace_python_web/test> 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory> 
WSGIScriptAlias /flasktest     D:/developer/workspace_python_web/test_for_deploy/test.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

step5. command: http -k install
step6. command: http -k start

At last, apache always throws errors like this:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of D:/Apache22/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load D:/Apache22/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: \xd5\xd2\xb2\xbb\xb5\xbd\xd6\xb8\xb6\xa8\xb5\xc4\xc4\xa3\xbf\xe9\xa1\xa3     .
```

I don't know why...

Comment: How did you get the .so file? You understand a .whl file is a zip file that you would need to unpack. You can't just rename the .whl file to have a .so extension.

Comment: the .so file is inside the /data directory